# Opening Camera RAW from bridge

Tags: photoshop, raw

I'm new to photo editing and need a little help.

I am running CS6.
When I have an image selected in Adobe bridge and select the shutter symbol or open in camera raw from the file menu I get the following message.
"Bridge's parent application is not active.
Bridge requires that a qualifying product has been launched at least once to enable this feature"

i can also have PS open at the same time and get the same message. The only way i get to open a picture in raw is from ps-open-look in my picture folders and select the image I want which then opens it in raw.

Comment: Check that this is a legitimate version of CS6 and your software (bridge, CS6, and ACR) are all compatible versions.  My GUESS is you have some combination of versions, like a newer ACR.  Each PS version only supports up to a given version ACR (ACR is what actually opens raw).

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Creative Cloud, just update everything.

If your version of PS doesn't match CS6 it could be a compatibility issue. You may also need to update your Adobe Raw compatibility too but I doubt it if you can see the Raw files in finder.